# How to use namespaces in non space classes?

Tags: php

Is there any way to use namespace classes in non-namespace classes?

Example:

```
// Note class A and B have no namespaces...
class A extends B {

 public function do() {
   $obj = new My\Namespace\SomeObject();
   return $obj;
 }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: What's wrong with the example code? Is it not possible? I'd say your example is fine.

Comment: Ah... Just noticed something - it might be worth nothing that `do` is a reserved word in PHP, since it's a control structure. This will cause an issue for the OP in any case (at least, as long as class A is in the global namespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [`use`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) operator:

```
<?php

use My\Namespace\SomeObject;

class A extends B 
{
    public function do()
    {
        $obj = new SomeObject();
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

Or you can use the fully qualified name, e.g:

```
$obj = new \My\Namespace\SomeObject();
```

Note the leading backslash.

**Edit**

On closer inspection there are actually a number of other points I would like to make:

1. As per @hakre's comments - if you are in the global namespace (this is the default/implicit namespace, as there is actually no non-namespace) then you do *not* need a leading backslash.
2. Using `Namespace` is a syntax error because it is a reserved word (case does not matter in PHP as many keywords including class, method and function names are case-insensitive).
3. Using `do` is a syntax error, as it is a also a reserved word (`do/while` control structure).

Comment: You can also alias the class http://php.net/class_alias.

Comment: Indeed you can - good point!

Comment: No blubbler bs. Sorry, but if your answer is the answer, then the question was the answer already because it did work w/o the use statement as well.

Comment: @hakre you're absolutely correct - I updated my answer, and there are some other issues worth noting as well so I figured I'd add those (even though I assume that the example the OP gave was purely for illustration). Anyway, thanks for the feedback, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should add global prefix operator to complete your *qualified name* to *fully qualified name*:

```
$obj = new \My\Namespace\SomeObject();
```